# Automated performance testing framework

Tags: java, performance, scala, testing

Is there a framework to write automated performance tests on the JVM ?

I would like to set some performance targets and flash a red light (or rather print a red console message) everytime the perfomance is below the goal.

I have some benchmarks written with Calliper that I run manually, however I would like the performance test suite, to be run automatically as I do for unit-testing.

No databases, or web server.

Comment: JUnit supports timings for tests, isn't that enough and you want something advanced?

Comment: Can you say what you would like which JUnit does not provide?

Comment: While junit may do the trick for some benchmarks which are long enough to be stable (despite JIT tricks, JVM warmup, system fluctuations, etc.), it will fail for most micro-benchmarks (which need a serious benchmarking suite like caliper).

Comment: Also it would be great if measurements for each commit where logged somewhat automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ScalaMeter](http://axel22.github.io/scalameter/) toolkit does exactly what I was looking for when I asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

Since 4-th version JUnit supports that functionality:

```
import org.junit.*;

public class JunitTest4 {

    // timings below are in milliseconds
    @Test(timeout = 1000)  
    public void infinity() {
        // will fail    
        while (true);  
    }  

}
```

But sadly, it just a basic functionality, not sure you'll be completely pleased: you can't measure something less than millisecond, you can't store history line for tests, you can't see how far you're from the goal.

Comment: It doesn't look like it does proper benchmarking either. Caliper handle things like computing stddev and power of the sequence, to find out if enough runs have been made, and getting back a value to prevent incorrect optimization.

Comment: Caliper does things like warming up the JIT, accounting for GCs, and all that stuff which JUnit just isn't built to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a performance testing specialist, so I can't judge how difficult this would be to implement, but it should be possible with JUnit Rules.

It would work similar to the @Test annotation mentioned by om-nom-nom, but you would provide a rule which for example runs each test 100 times for warm up than runs it 100 times and calculates the stdev and fails the test when average time is 2 stdevs larger then the set timeoiut. ... Or whatever the rules should be.

Here is an [article to JUnit Rules](http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2011/07/24/rules-in-junit-4-9-beta-3/).

Basically [the same approach should work with ScalaTest](http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2011/08/28/manipulating-test-execution-with-scalatest/)

Comment: So, basically, you reimplement Caliper inside a test? IMHO, the true answer to this question is "no".

Comment: Well ... I tried to say "no" in a more helpful way by pointing out some options. And the recommendation isn't to implement it in a test but in a test wrapper which can be used for various tests.